# How to close EXTJS form panel when clicked in rest of the browser area.

Tags: java, extjs4.2

I am Working with extjs 4.2.1 and I was trying to close log in form panel when user clicks out side the Log In panel(in white area of browser).
I want to know which event should I used to check if user has clicked out side log in panel in extjs, and how to close panel using that event.

Can any one help me to understand it in better and easy way or any small code snippet which will make me easy to understand.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

You can register a listener on the body element.  Here's a simple example:

```
var panel = new Ext.Panel({
    cls: 'the-panel',
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

Ext.getBody().on('click', function (event) {
    var targEl = Ext.get(event.getTarget());

    if (targEl === panel.getEl() || targEl.up('.the-panel')) {
        //clicked on or within the panel, do nothing
    } else {
        panel.close();
    }
});
```

You'll likely want to enhance the example above such that the event is unregistered once the panel is closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
handler: function(button, e) {
    success: function(form, action) {
        button.up('.window').close();
    },
}
```